# Create effect top image is overlaid by content when sliding up

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have to create an effect like in the images but I don't know how to do it (and also don't know how to call this effect to search). You can see in the pictures, at first we have an image at the top of page. After that, when we scroll up, the image moves up while the content moves with higher speed to cover the image. Can you give me a link or a suggestion?
[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Finally]

Comment: The images just appear to be a normal `UIScrollView`

Comment: I don't think it is only a normal UIScrollView. You can see the image frame becomes smaller while the content moves up.

Comment: To me it just looks like the `UIImageView` is scrolling up with the `UIScrollView`, not changing in size. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Here is the clip for illustration.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GiY8WnMDwM&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Still looks like it's scrolling, just at a different rate as the text content. Some kind of offset rather.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all take imageview and scrollview in your apps with **IBOutlet**.

In your **YourViewController.h** file

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *imagev;

@property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scr;
```

In your **YourViewController.m** file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    scr.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,850);
    scr.decelerationRate = UIScrollViewDecelerationRateNormal;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Set imagev frame according to scrolling in scrollview delegate.

## pragma mark - ScrollView Delegate

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)callerScrollView
{
    
    NSLog(@"%f",callerScrollView.contentOffset.y);
    
    [imagev setFrame:CGRectMake(imagev.frame.origin.x, - 0.5 *callerScrollView.contentOffset.y, imagev.frame.size.width, imagev.frame.size.height)];

}
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, your solution is great. I've made a demo project on Github for that.https://github.com/lenhhoxung86/TopScroll