# Add parallax effect when scrolling through images in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have been making a UIScrollView with paging Enabled and it scroll through photos like a Normal UICollectionView. I want the image view to have a parallax effect as i scroll.

I wanted to have an effect like this when i scroll
https://github.com/MP0w/MPParallaxCollection/blob/master/img/inaction.gif

Any helps
Thanks in Advance 
Aryan

Comment: See this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24749952/create-effect-top-image-is-overlaid-by-content-when-sliding-up/24750746#24750746

Comment: Hi Kirit  i have edited the answer to tell what i exactly want.. What you sent was not i really wanted

Answer (score 0):

The parallax effect that you get in the springboard application was introduced with iOS 7 and is implemented using a class called `UIMotionEffect`.

In a quick search on Google for Parallax and `UIMotionEffect` I found dozens of tutorial results.

The basic technique involves creating an instance of some subclass of UIMotionEffect using the `init(keyPath: String, type: UIInterpolatingMotionEffectType)` method.  The `keyPath` would be the property of the animated view you wish to provide the effect to and the `type:` argument specifies when the effect should be applied.

Comment: Hi Scott i have edited the answer to tell what i exactly want as if i use  UIInterpolatingMotion it makes parallax effect when i actually tilt the phone.